# Which loss function will converge well in multi-label image classification task?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I've trained a multi-label multi-class image classifier by using `sigmoid` as output activation function and `binary_crossentropy` as loss function.
The accuracy curve for validation is showing up-down fluctuation while loss curve at few epochs is showing weird(very high) values.

Following is the Accuracy and loss-curve for fine-tuned(last block) `VGG19` model with `Dropout` and `BatchNormalization`.

[Accuracy curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6pfM.png)
[loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBb3R.png)

Accuracy and loss-curve for fine-tuned(last block) `VGG19` model with `Dropout`, `BatchNormalization` and `Data Augmentation`.

[accuracy curve with data augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SOmG.png)
[loss curve with data augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHB4R.png)

I've trained the classifier with 1800 training images(5-labels) with 100 validation images. The optimizer I'd used is `SGD((lr=0.001, momentum=0.99)`.
Can anyone explain why loss-curve is getting so much weird or high values at some eochs?
Should I use different loss-function? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - all is well. Your loss curve doesn't say much, especially 'spikes in the loss curve'. They're totally allowed, your model is still training. You should look at your accuracy curve, and that one goes up pretty normal I think.

Comment: Thank you @Frederik for your reply.
Still I'm unable to understand, why are these spikes in loss-curve.

Well, this model is predicting 81/100 all correct labels with hamming loss of approx 6%

Comment: Why? It's coincidence. The model's weights at that moment in the training time were good to fit it's previously seen training data, but apparently it failed big time on the test data. It's still learning. Imagine a kid trying to learn something. Let's say after a little practice, it thinks it has learnt a shortcut to achieve it's task, only later to find out it was only a shortcut, and it doesn't always work, so it learns the correct way of doing the task.

Comment: Thank you @Frederik, I got it.